# How to design cascading font style relationships between parent elements and text elements

Tags: html, css, sass

This is a pretty basic thing, but something that has always seemed weird to me. I develop sites for content management systems where I cannot always reliably expect a content author to use the correct markup. Many times, they do not even know what a p tag is.

So let's say I have a description element that should be styled a certain way, separate from my global paragraph styles. Inside of it will be text, ideally in a paragraph tag, but who knows, maybe it won't be. To work around this, I add the styles both to the parent and to the paragraph tag:

```
.description {
        font-family: $LatoLight;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.25;

        p {
            font-family: $LatoLight;
            color: white;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.25;
        }
    }
```

This seems like repetative and overkill, but if I only add the styles to the p, the author may not use a p tag, and if I only apply the styles to the parent, global or other paragraph styles will overtake the styles of the parent. I also generally do the same thing with anchor tag colors. Sometimes I can enforce the tag with my backend code, but I'm really more interested in the solution from purely styling architecture.

What do other people do? Is this a bad strategy? To date, the above styling has been the most reliable for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
.description {
    font-family: $LatoLight;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.25;

    *{
        font-family: inherit;
        color: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you safely assume that the author (or whatever WYSIWYG is being used) will insert an element at all? Be it a `p` or `div, span, blockquote, article, main, section` basically the most commonly used text-containing elements.

A few options would be:

1. Make sure the output is always going into a container with an id and/or a class (to make it the styles harder to override).
2. Make sure what ever WYSIWYG editor (if using one) will only output a handful of controllable elements
3. Ask the authors to only use a handful of elements

There aren't really that many HTML elements to choose from anyway.

The CSS:

```
.description,
.description p,
.description span,
.description td,
.description article,
.description main,
.description blockquote,
.description section,
.description any_selector_here,
.description div {
    font-family: $LatoLight;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.25;
}
```

This way you are only writing your styles once.